# Google Sheets formula for conditional formatting: "if cell contains exact text text" then

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to write a basic conditional formatting on a cell so "if cell C58 contains the string 'long cont' then turn cell D58 turn it green".

Any ideas what the syntax is?

Thank you.

Ed

Comment: umm - click the cell, open the conditional formatting dialog, and you'll have your answer. There's no formula

Comment: this only lets you colour the cell you are referring to in that dialogue box, nothing about affecting other cells depeneding on the value on the cell you have selecteed. There is option to put in a custom formula.

Comment: yes there is a place to put a custom formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click the cell you want to highlight.
2. Open the conditional formatting dialog.
3. Select "custom formula is".
4. Type your formula, e.g. `=(I192 = "yes")`.

[image: custom rules for conditional formatting in google sheets]